# Multiplas imagens dentro de um Image Button com padding

Tags: android

Possuo um `ImageButton` e dentro do mesmo preciso colocar 5 imagens ao mesmo tempo, estando uma no centro e as demais em volta fazendo alusão a estar expandindo.

Sendo assim como coloco todas as imagens ao mesmo tempo no `ImageButton` e entre elas colocar um padding ou diferentes tamanhos?

[image: Imagem exemplo]

Comment: Pode colocar um desenho de exemplo?

Comment: 5 imagens ao mesmo tempo eu entendi, só não entendi a alusão a estar expandindo! Poderia colocar um exemplo do que desejas? Esta imagens serão fixas? Ou alteram? quais os tamanhos?

Comment: o resultado esperado foi colocado na questão, cada parte é uma imagem, e os tamanhos de todos são iguais

Answer (score 1):

Tendo em conta que um Image Button tem UMA source, o melhor será editar a imagem em software próprio e de seguida definir a nova imagem como source do botão.

Se precisar criar efeitos, terá de ter várias imagens para serem exibidas em momentos diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um `<layer-list>` com vários círculos dentro, utilizando o atributo `dashGap` e `dashWidht` e colocar como `src` do seu `ImageView`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="40dp"
                android:left="40dp"
                android:right="40dp"
                android:top="40dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:dashGap="3dp"
                android:dashWidth="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="40dp"
                android:left="40dp"
                android:right="40dp"
                android:top="40dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:dashGap="3dp"
                android:dashWidth="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="40dp"
                android:left="40dp"
                android:right="40dp"
                android:top="40dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:dashGap="3dp"
                android:dashWidth="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:dashGap="3dp"
                android:dashWidth="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Imagem resultado]

Comment: o uso é muito bom, mas não preciso criar as linhas e sim usar as imagens que já possuo

Comment: @AleffMatos voce não pode replica-las em forma de drawable?

Comment: Até posso mas pensando no passo seguinte que é animar para dar um efeito de onda ao carregar, usar as imagens propriamente seria mais fácil

Comment: @AleffMatos Se o seu problema é a animação o que deve ter são as várias imagens que compõem a animação para depois serem atribuídas uma a uma ao *ImageButton*. No fundo é seguir a resposta do Wildcat.